# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, function, compiler-errors, this, arrow-functions

I have a file .ts and get this error for the following code:

```
const hulk={
    nombre:'Hulk',
    smash(){

        setTimeout(function(){   
            console.log(`${ this.nombre} smash!`); //HERE is the error but IDK why
        },1000);

        setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(`${ this.nombre} smash!`);
        },1000);
        
    }
}
hulk.smash();
```

I am learning to use arrow functions and the difference between using arrow functions and using functions, but I get the error when I put the word "this" in the function, because when I use "this" in the arrow function everything is okay.

I tried adding

```
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

to

```
tsconfig.json
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside `setTimeout` refers to the function context, not to the hulk object. Arrow functions don't create their own context (their own this) since they inherit it.

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)